# Macbook pro GPU temperature Limit

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu, temperature

On GPU intense tasks like gaming, my laptop starts with increasing the GPU temperature and frequency ( to 85 degrees and max GPU frequency ) then after 5 min or so reduce the temp to 67 degrees Celsius and GPU core frequency and stay there.
This happened both on macOS and Windows Bootcamp.
How to set GPU temperature to the usual standard (80-degree celsius )? 
Every laptop I owned use 80-degree celsius as max GPU temperature.

My Laptop Specs :
15 inch MacBook Pro 2018 
Cpu: Intel 8850H
GPU: AMD Pro 560X

[ It has a T2 Security Chip ]

Comment: Two Example: Asus k550jk with GTX850m - Lenovo Y50 with GTX 960m

Comment: I must explain, my problem related to GPU temperature.

Comment: [Is it normal for the iMac 5K's GPU to be at 90℃ with fan on constantly?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284728/) slightly related.

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I want the GPU to stay at a higher temperature so the GPU memory and core frequency increases. 67-degree Celsius is too low.

Comment: When GPUs run hot enough to the point the cooling system can no longer remove enough heat from the system, the GPU dumps processes resulting in a drop in temperature and frequency. What if you increase your fan speeds, tinker with the ranges and try to find the sweet spot from preventing thermal throttling?  If you increased the fan speed slightly it would only buy you a brief amount of additional time. Would maxing out your fan speed hurt you performance of the fly gets too cold? Maybe the trick could be to blast fan speed periodically using a temp range triggering a timer?

Comment: Let's say 85 degrees is too hot in the beginning for GPU. But Why it goes down to 67 degrees and stay there forever? I think normally fans kick in and the system keeps a consistent temperature around 80 degrees. I tried to maximum fan speed with "Macs Fan Control" but that behavior didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved on Bootcamp with GPU Driver's provided by AMD.

https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/apple-boot-camp
Make sure to remove Apple stock GPU Driver with "Display Driver Uninstaller" on Safe mode.
Do not use the "Apple" or "bootcampdrivers.com" drivers.
You must install Radeon pro driver ( It has blue system tray icon )